# Placing links under input

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So, I made this website where you have links under an input. I want the 4 links to be placed under the input like this for example [image: This image].

```css
 .q-links {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: horizonal;
  color: rgb(140, 140, 140);
  
  .search-bar {
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: none;
    padding: 0.75rem 1rem;
    /* Adjust padding for better input size */
    width: calc(100% - 2rem);
    /* Use calc() for responsive width */
    margin: 0.5rem;
    /* Adjust margin for spacing */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* Include padding in width calculation */
    width: 60%;
    margin-left: -2em;
    flex-grow: 1;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 50px #000000;
    z-index: 5;
  }
```

```html
<header class="nav-bar">

  <img src="Final New RFS Logo 2021-01 (2).png" class="logo" alt="RFS Logo">

  <div style="margin: 0; padding: 0; display: flex; align-items: center; flex-direction: row; width: auto;">

    <input class="search-bar" type="text" placeholder="Search Anything at RFS">

    <ul class="q-links">
      <li>Students</li>
      <li>Staff</li>
      <li>Parents</li>
      <li>Alumni</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

I expected it to have the 4 links under under the input exactly, and not like this

[image]

Additionally, I am not sure what HTML to add or remove in order to have all the links below the input, and never rime I did try flexes, ot ended up altering the input shape and bugging it up.

Comment: You're missing a closing brace in your CSS and a closing header tag in your HTML. Please revise to provide valid code.

Comment: `flex-direction: horizontal` is invalid. You may want to check [some documentation for the property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) to find the valid values.

Comment: Protip: Don't use inline styles, especially when you also have a stylesheet. It makes your project much more difficult to work with and maintain .

Comment: Welcome! `display: flex;` on your `<div>` is causing this. You can change `flex-direction: row;` to `flex-direction: column` and it should get you what you want. That said, you're missing a closing brace `}` in your CSS for the `.q-links` styles

Comment: Change your div flex-direction to column and its child will be displayed in columns. li are already displaying inline so you will get what you want